# How to deploy shiny app in azure ml compute instances with shiny server

Tags: r, azure, shiny, shiny-server, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML I have created compute instance and install RStudio application, I am able to create shiny app in RStudio. However, I need to host this shiny app in shiny server

Is there any possibility that I can host shiny app in shiny server in azure ML compute instance

Answer (score 1):

We need to create virtual machine to deploy the shiny app to the shiny service in azure ML.

Directly from compute instance it is not possible to do so. Follow the below procedure to create the virtual machine and implement the procedure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Log into the VM and follow the procedure mentioned in the [link](https://canovasjm.netlify.app/2020/01/08/deploy-you-own-shiny-server-on-azure/)

Thank you **canovasjm** for the blog for support.